# Seeking the longer paper for which John Conway's "An enumeration of knots and links" is "an abbreviated form"

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory

I'm reading the paper "An enumeration of knots and links, and some of their algebraic properties" by John Conway.

The first sentence of the first section reads

> This paper is an abbreviated form of a longer one in which completeness is proved by means of a process for locating any knot or link within the range of the table, but for reasons of space, we only sketch this process here.

No further reference is given. I can't find any information about such a paper online, nor have I found a comprehensive list of Conway's articles. Does anyone know if this article was ever published and provide a reference for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked for this paper before, and I've never found any trace of it.

Searching through MathSciNet for papers by Conway with "knot" or "knots" in the title, these are the only ones that appear:

- 1967, "An enumeration of knots and links, and some of their algebraic properties."
- with C. McA. Gordon, 1975, "A group to classify knots."
- with C. McA. Gordon, 1983, "Knots and links in spatial graphs."

Then, searching for MathSciNet reviews that mention MR0258014 (the 1967 paper), none of the papers are by Conway.  I also looked at papers in MathSciNet that cited this one up to the year 2000, but, again, none by Conway. (I only went this far because there are 387 papers that cite it.)

I don't know that it was never published, but, if it was, I've never seen anyone cite it! (In one paper I read a while back, I thought I had a lead since it cited "An enumeration of knots and links and some of their *related* properties," but it was merely a mistake.)

Answer (score -1):

I know the question was posted a long time ago, but I just did a Google search for "enumeration of knots", and this question came up in the results, as did this link, which is to a PDF of the full length paper the original poster was asking about:  [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/conway.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/conway.pdf)

Comment: No, unfortunately. This is the "abbreviated" paper. It contains the sentence quoted by the OP at the beginning of section 1 (after the introduction).